# Adjust argument of a function

Tags: fractions

How to adjust the position of an argument of a function in a fraction?

For example, in my text I have this:

```
\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

 \begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\dd \widetilde{\overline{T}}}{\dd t}(\beta_n,\gamma_n,t)  
 \end{equation}
```

The final result is:

[image]

How to adjust the argument for some like that:

[image]

Comment: don't use `\rm` in latex (it has not been defined by default since 1994, although some classes define it for compatibility with older documents)

Comment: My impression is that this is mathematically wrong: the argument is to the derivative, not to its numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the argument to be next to the numerator, so you can just make it part of the numerator. Using `\mathrlap` (from`mathtools`) you can hide it's width. Then the fraction rule will not be extended. This might lead to following text being overprinted because TeX doesn't know about the width of the argument, so you should use `\hphantom` to add sufficient horizontal space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\usepackage{mathtools}        
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\dd \widetilde{\overline{T}}\mathrlap{(\beta_n,\gamma_n,t)}}{\dd t}\hphantom{(\beta_n,\gamma_n,t)}  
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this other simpler code, and loaging `esdiff` for a simpler typing of the derivative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{\alpha}\diff{\widetilde{\mkern1mu\overline{\mkern-1mu T}}}{t}{(\beta_n,\gamma_n,t)\atop }
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]